# How to add and mount volumes for EC2 instance with Ansible

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ansible

I am trying to learn the Ansible with all my AWS stuff. So the first task which I want to do is creation the basic EC2 instance with mounted volumes.

I wrote the Playbook according to Ansible docs, but it doesn't really work. My Playbook:

```
# The play operates on the local (Ansible control) machine.
- name: Create a basic EC2 instance v.1.1.0 2015-10-14
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: false

# Vars.
  vars:
      hostname: Test_By_Ansible
      keypair: MyKey
      instance_type: t2.micro
      security_group: my security group   
      image: ami-d05e75b8                 # Ubuntu Server 14.04 LTS (HVM)
      region: us-east-1                   # US East (N. Virginia)
      vpc_subnet_id: subnet-b387e763      
      sudo: True
      locale: ru_RU.UTF-8

# Launch instance. Register the output.
  tasks:
    - name: Launch instance
      ec2:
         key_name: "{{ keypair }}"
         group: "{{ security_group }}"
         instance_type: "{{ instance_type }}"
         image: "{{ image }}"
         region: "{{ region }}"
         vpc_subnet_id: "{{ vpc_subnet_id }}"
         assign_public_ip: yes
         wait: true
         wait_timeout: 500
         count: 1                         # number of instances to launch
         instance_tags:
            Name: "{{ hostname }}"
            os: Ubuntu
            type: WebService
      register: ec2

    # Create and attach a volumes.
    - name: Create and attach a volumes
      ec2_vol:
         instance: "{{ item.id }}"
         name: my_existing_volume_Name_tag
         volume_size: 1   # in GB
         volume_type: gp2
         device_name: /dev/sdf
         with_items: ec2.instances
      register: ec2_vol

    # Configure mount points.
    - name: Configure mount points - mount device by name
      mount: name=/system src=/dev/sda1 fstype=ext4 opts='defaults nofail 0 2' state=present
      mount: name=/data src=/dev/xvdf fstype=ext4 opts='defaults nofail 0 2' state=present
```

But this Playbook crushes on volumes mount with error:

```
fatal: [localhost] => One or more undefined variables: 'item' is undefined
```

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have copy/pasted a lot of stuff all at once, and rather than needing a specific bit of information that SO can help you with, you need to go off and learn the basics of Ansible so you can think through all the individual bits that don't match up in this playbook.

Let's look at the specific error that you're hitting - `item is undefined`. It's triggered here:

```
# Create and attach a volumes.
- name: Create and attach a volumes
  ec2_vol:
     instance: "{{ item.id }}"
     name: my_existing_volume_Name_tag
     volume_size: 1   # in GB
     volume_type: gp2
     device_name: /dev/sdf
     with_items: ec2.instances
  register: ec2_vol
```

This task is meant to be looping through every item in a list, and in this case the list is `ec2.instances`. It isn't, because `with_items` should be de-indented so it sits level with register.

If you had a list of instances (which you don't, as far as I can see), it'd use the `id` for the for each one in that `{{ item.id }}` line... but then probably throw an error, because I don't think they'd all be allowed to have the same name.

Go forth and study, and you can figure out this kind of detail.

Comment: the answer is not complete since did not mention how to mount added device.